# Why is my jquery val() not picking the actual selected value from my select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I type `$('select[id*=lstAdvGradYear]')` chrome gives me

```
<select name="Views\ContentArea$ctl00$lstAdvGradYear" id="Views\ContentArea_ctl00_lstAdvGradYear" class="ddReplace" style="display: none; ">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>

</select>
```

When I type `$('select[id*=lstAdvGradYear]').val()` chrome replies with `"2016"`.

When I type `$('select[id*=lstAdvGradYear] option:selected ').val()` chrome also replies with `"2016"`

When I type `$('select[id*=lstAdvGradYear] option:selected')` chrome replies with `[<option value="2016">2016</option>]`

What am I doing wrong?

I have verified that there are no other drop downs with a similar name

---

**EDIT:** To be clear, my issue is that `.val()` should be returning 2013 NOT 2016

Comment: It shows 2013. http://jsfiddle.net/gaeSC/ . What version of jquery do you use?

Comment: Huh?  I'm trying to figure out why val() is not giving me 2013 since that is the selected element.  I know the difference between val() and not using val()

Comment: I know. I'm sorry. I deleted my comment because I was confused as to what you were asking. After re-reading I realized I was answering something very different.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more information for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in the first two cases, you invoked the $.val() function, but in the last case, you didn't.

$.val() returns the value of an HTML element.  $() returns an object representing one or more html elements, with a number of methods you can invoke, including $.val()

**Update:** It appears that according to the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), the value to the right of `id*=` is supposed to be enclosed in quotation marks.  Does that make any difference?

Comment: This has nothing to do with not using val().  My issue is that Val() is returning the incorrect value, it should be returning 2013 adn not 2016 since 2013 is the selected option

Comment: I, too, was initially confused. He says they are all returning "2016" but his HTML shows "2013" as being selected. It's not a matter of getting val or element, but getting the wrong val/element.

Comment: Your update is correct, putting it in quotation marks fixed it.  Thank you, I was pulling my hair out

Comment: `[attr=val]` does not always require quote, if just letters or no special characters are used. It's worth noting that a similar problem will happen if you are getting the wrong `option` element value from `val()` due to multiple `selected="selected"` elements.